# How to convert improper CFG to weakly equivalent one?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

In wikipedia there's the definition for "Proper CFG".

> A context-free grammar is said to be proper, if it has
>
> $$\text{no unreachable symbols}: \forall N \in V: \exists \alpha,\beta
> > \in (V\cup\Sigma)^*: S \stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow} \alpha{N}\beta$$
>   $$\text{no unproductive symbols}: \forall N \in V: \exists w \in
> > \Sigma^*: N \stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow} w$$ $$\text{no ε-productions}:
> > \neg\exists N \in V: (N, \varepsilon) \in R$$ $$\text{no cycles}:
> > \neg\exists N \in V: N \stackrel{+}{\Rightarrow} N$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Proper_CFGs

It's also stated that non-proper CFGs can be transformed into "weakly equivalent" CFGs:

> In formal language theory, weak equivalence of two grammars means they generate the same set of strings, i.e. that the formal language they generate is the same.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(formal_languages)

but I cannot find the algorithm for doing this.

How is it done?

Comment: Please repeat the definitions here so a) readers don't have to search and guess what you mean and b) your question makes sense even after Wikipedia changes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Wikipedia does supply a reference to a standard textbook. Second, since a proper grammar is one without unproductive symbols, to make a grammar proper all you have to do is erase all unproductive symbols and all productions involving them.